# Getting help from web cloud services (calling from asp.net mvc site)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, cloud

I have a website, but some of the back-end infrastructure is little slow.

So I am planning to get help from `CLOUD`, I haven't decided which one yet.

I need to know does Microsoft `Cloud` does the same thing.

What I need is following,

1) Have database on external web resource.

2) Have code and http enabled methods that I will write in C# and place it on `Cloud`.

3) And call the methods in step 3 from my asp.net `MVC` wesite's codebehind and client side(javascript).

I need to know if I get support from Microsoft `Cloud` platform, will I get the solution required in above 3 mentioned points?

And if I get support from Microsoft `Cloud`, then the coding syntax for `SQL`, will be same as if I run queries against normal `SQL Server` database

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly in that you are looking to have a cloud hosted SQL database and HTTP access to this database through custom C# code, then yes to all three of these.

You can set up your database as an Azure SQL database and create an ASP.NET WebAPI application to open up your database to HTTP calls as you see fit.  Then you can use the REST client of your choice to access your database from your MVC controllers or through Javascript in your views.

Also, yes, SQL syntax for Azure SQL is the same as for regular SQL Server.

Comment: so u are saying I can create rest service and upload it to azure and I can access it from my app?

Comment: Yep.  You can do that.